# Drag marker with circle and vice versa in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to "stick" marker to the center of circle? So when I drag marker circle also moves and vice versa.

```
options = {
                    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.35,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: "#0000FF",
                    fillOpacity: 0.20
                };
                options.map = context.map;
                options.radius = radius;
                options.center = center;
                context.circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.19335, -3.92695),
        map: _map,
        title: "",
        draggable: True
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind the marker position to the circle's center property.

```
// Add the circle for this city to the map.
var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: citymap[city].center,
    draggable: true,
    map: map
});
marker.bindTo("position", cityCircle, "center");
```

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
  // Create the map.
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  // Construct the circle for each value in citymap.
  // Note: We scale the area of the circle based on the population.
  for (var city in citymap) {
    var populationOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      draggable: true,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
    };
    // Add the circle for this city to the map.
    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle(populationOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: citymap[city].center,
      draggable: true,
      map: map
    });
    marker.bindTo("position", cityCircle, "center");
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// This example creates circles on the map, representing
// populations in North America.

// First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
var citymap = {};
citymap['chicago'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.878113, -87.629798),
  population: 2714856
};
citymap['newyork'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.714352, -74.005973),
  population: 8405837
};
citymap['losangeles'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234, -118.243684),
  population: 3857799
};
citymap['vancouver'] = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.25, -123.1),
  population: 603502
};

var cityCircle;
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" ></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Not that I know of [marker to circle](http://jsfiddle.net/jku5k890/), [circle to marker](http://jsfiddle.net/jku5k890/1/).